# how to convert a file object to a url

Tags: javascript, file, object, url, frontend

I have a javascript file object like so:

[image]

and I would like to turn it into a url so that the file can be accessed through the url. How would I go about generating a url for this file through javascript?

The javascript for the file object is something like this:

```
const file = new File(["blob data"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "image/png",

});
```

I would like to pass this `file` variable somewhere and have a url generated for it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

This one was really one google search away my friend, unless I misunderstood your needs?

`objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(object);`

[createObjectURL on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: hm no you didnt misunderstand my needs; I actually tried this but for some reason the url it generates does not render to correct image; So was looking for alternatives

Comment: Mhh.. I see, i'm really confused at how you have a file `type: "image/png"` AND `name: "fileName.txt"`

Comment: ah lol I just copy and pasted that example from the mozilla site, its not actually like that in my code; Edited